# How to combine bits from 2 bytes in Java?

Tags: java, byte, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I have 1 number which require 9 bits and the bits spread into 2 bytes (Most Significant Byte and Least Significant Byte).
The MSB is like:

```
0?????[Bit8][Bit7]
```

And the LSB is like:

```
0[Bit6][Bit5][Bit4][Bit3][Bit2][Bit1][Bit0]
```

My number consists on 9 bits from Bit0 to Bit8. `?` indicates either 1 or 0.

So, how do I get my number?
I can think of shifting the bits in MSB left by 7 bits and then combine it with LSB to form a 16 bit number. However, how can I avoid losing Bit8 when shifting MSB left by 7 bits?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java bitwise operators are done on 32-bit ints in this case, so you don't lose [bit8] when you shift to the left.

```
    int msb = 0xFF;
    int lsb = 0xFF;
    int result = ( ( msb & 0x3 ) << 7 ) | ( lsb & 0x7F );
    System.out.println(result == 0x1FF);
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't think the `&0x7F` part is redundant though. `result = ( ( msb & 0x3 ) << 7 ) | ( lsb )` is sufficient :D

Answer (score 1):

Additionally , you can try the BitSet class
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html

for working on arbitrary bit lengths [ example size 9 here]